# NSDate comparison showing wrong value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, nsdate

iam comparing two dates ,but when i type the two dates into a string variable its working but when iam passing those valuse to data comparing methode its not working why?

this is the code iam using ?

```
NSString *dateString =@"2013-05-12 22:10:02";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];



NSString *dateString1 = @"2013-03-04 07:59:08";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
NSDate *dateFromString1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];

if ([dateFromString compare:dateFromString1] == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"1 is later than 2");

} else if ([dateFromString compare:dateFromString1] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"1 is earlier than 2");

} else
{
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

**When iam passing the dates(nsstring format) to a methode

```
(int)compareDate:(NSString *)date1:(NSString *)date2
```

in that method i wrote the above compare code
so iam calling this methode like

```
[self compareDate:date1:date2]
```

and iam always getting  "dates are same " value???? when i type the date manually themn iam getting exact answer ??why is that?**

Comment: Probably because they are both null. Check your format string.  Notice you are using MM for both minutes and months? `-___-` and SS instead of ss for seconds?? `-______________________-`

Comment: ok i wikll check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code by below code. "mm" format is for minutes and "MM" for months. and use "ss" for seconds not "SS".  Read apple documentations for detailed information about date formatters.

```
 NSString *dateString =@"2013-05-12 22:10:02";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];



    NSString *dateString1 = @"2013-03-04 07:59:08";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];

    if ([dateFromString compare:dateFromString1] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"1 is later than 2");

    } else if ([dateFromString compare:dateFromString1] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        NSLog(@"1 is earlier than 2");

    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"dates are the same");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the date formatter.Make use of `mm` instead of `MM` for minutes  and `ss` instead of `SS` for seconds.

```
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: mm instead of MM for **minutes** -1

Comment: @borrrden sorry it was a typo.Thanks